# Need Help Creating Arches Around Main Structure - Array Usage?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry

everyone, I created a building shaped like a bowl, inspired by the Brasília Cathedral (though with some different measurements).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_of_Bras%C3%ADlia

Similar to the Cathedral, I want to create "arches" around the main structure...

I've tried making an arch, and I know I should probably use something like an array, but I just can't figure out how to use it properly!

I took a look at other questions about arrays, but I confess I couldn't find the answer. The funny thing is, I know it's something simple haha!

Could someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: You want that circular distribution of the arches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cube, in *Edit* mode move it away from its origin, scale it on Z, in *Object* mode create an empty at the exact same location:

[image]

Give your object an *Array* modifier, *Count* > 16 or whatever, enable *Object Offset* instead of *Relative Offset* and choose the empty as object:

[image]

Rotate the empty 22.5° on Z:

[image]

Model your object as needed, the instances will deform as well:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.
Btw, your structure is really nice haha
haha

Answer (score 3):

1. Add an Array modifier and turn on Object Offset
2. Add an empty in the scene (technically any object will do)
3. Set this empty as the object for the offset
4. Make sure the location of your empty and the arches is the same. 
   The empty will most probably be in the center. Place your 3D cursor in the center. Select the arch > right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor.
5. Now simply rotate the empty around the Z-axis.

Result:

[image]

Comment: exactly!
Thanks!!!!!